# Styling specific weekday head row in React Daypicker & shadcn/ui

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, react-day-picker

I'm using shadcn/ui's library for a project and it's going pretty well so far. However, I have an issue with styling the inner parts of the Calendar component, particularly the weekdays head row.

Out of the box, Shadcn's Calendar component looks like this:
[image: Default Calendar UI Style]

I'm trying to style the calendar weekday head row into this:
[image]

Basically my problem is that I can't find a way to change the "Su" weekday name's text color to red.

I've tried manipulating the `classNames` object directly in the `calendar.tsx` file. But so far the only property that I could find that could style the weekday head row is the `head_cell` property, and that affects all weekday names in the row. I was wondering if there are any other alternatives to styling the weekdays.

Link to the `calendar.tsx` file in the official shadcn/ui github repository: https://github.com/shadcn-ui/ui/blob/main/apps/www/registry/default/ui/calendar.tsx

Comment: nevermind, I found a solution: add the 'first' pseudo class from tailwind css to the head_cell property